# How to change the numbering in duplicate path aliases?

Tags: 7, path-aliases

All my node paths have a URL alias, provided by [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto). The pattern is `[node:title]`. The generated aliases for nodes with the same title are by default

- **title**,
- **title-0**,
- **title-1**,

etc. I would like to change this numbering into

- **title-1**,
- **title-2**,
- **title-3**,

etc. So, when a node with the title *Test* is submitted, a URL alias **test** should be generated. Once a second node with the same title is published, another alias **test-1** should be created for the first node and a new alias **test-2** should be added for the newly created node.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pathauto_alias_uniquify(&$alias, $source, $langcode)`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!pathauto!pathauto.inc/function/pathauto_alias_uniquify/7) is the function that does the suffixing to generate uniqueness. It has a hard-coded value that starts at 0.

However, Pathauto evokes a hook, [`hook_pathauto_is_alias_reserved()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21pathauto%21pathauto.api.php/function/hook_pathauto_is_alias_reserved/7) when it checks for uniqueness when generating its path alias. If you have a custom module evoke this hook, you can check reject instances of the -0 suffixing and tell pathauto to move onto the next entry.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_pathauto_is_alias_reserved().
 */
function MYMODULE_pathauto_is_alias_reserved($alias, $source, $langcode) {
  // Return FALSE when the alias ends with '-0'
  $zero_suffix = variable_get('pathauto_separator', '-') . '0';
  return (substr($alias, -strlen($zero_suffix)) == $zero_suffix);
}
```

This might catch entries that legitimately have "-0" in the path, but I'll leave to the reader to devise a workaround for that scenario.

Comment: Thanks, I adapted your code to start the suffixing from 2. Now, for consistency, I would like to add a new alias **test-1** for the first node with title *Test* (that means this node will have two aliases: **test** and **test-1**). Which hook should I use to do that? Or do you advise against this? I will already give you an upvote.

Comment: Look at the [pathauto.api.php](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21pathauto%21pathauto.api.php/7) to see what's available. You can use [`path_save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/path_save/7.x) to duplicate/modify the created pathauto path.